# crosswise implicit / explicit type conversation of records in pascal

Tags: operator-overloading, record, pascal, helper, freepascal

I want to implement a crosswise type conversation of two record types in pascal. But I receive the error "Error: Procedure or Function expected". This is the relevant code:

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
interface
{$modeswitch advancedrecords}
uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TRGBA8 = packed record
    r,
    g,
    b,
    a: byte;
    public
      constructor Create(r_in, g_in, b_in, a_in: byte);
  end;

  TRGBA16 = packed record
    r,
    g,
    b,
    a: word;
    public
      constructor Create(r_in, g_in, b_in, a_in: word);
      class operator Explicit(const c_in: TRGBA16): TRGBA8; inline;
      class operator :=(const c_in: TRGBA16): TRGBA8; inline;
  end;

  TRGBA8Helper = record helper for TRGBA8
    public
      class operator Explicit(const c_in: TRGBA8): TRGBA16;
  end;
```

I receive the error at the declaration of the Operator Explicit of TRGBA8Helper. How can I archive a crosswise type conversation. Thanks in advance.

I'm using Lazarus 1.8.2 and FPC 3.0.4 from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Class and record helpers do not support operator overloading, at least not in Delphi. You would have to declare a function in the helper instead.

Comment: Have you looked at https://wiki.freepascal.org/Operator_overloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. My first attempt was derived from the TPoint class of the FPC source (/usr/share/fpcsrc/3.0.4/rtl/objpas/types.pp). In wiki.freepascal.org/Operator_overloading can be found a link to the docs: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch15.html. This Page contains examples. So I came to this solution:

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
interface
{$modeswitch advancedrecords}
uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TRGBA8 = packed record
    r,
    g,
    b,
    a: byte;
    public
      constructor Create(r_in, g_in, b_in, a_in: byte);
  end;

  TRGBA16 = packed record
    r,
    g,
    b,
    a: word;
    public
      constructor Create(r_in, g_in, b_in, a_in: word);
  end;

operator Explicit(const c_in: TRGBA16): TRGBA8; inline;
operator :=(const c_in: TRGBA16): TRGBA8; inline;
operator Explicit(const c_in: TRGBA8): TRGBA16; inline;
operator :=(const c_in: TRGBA8): TRGBA16; inline;
```

So no helper record is needed and the error doesn't occurs.